# Docker: MariaDB Container Unhealthy - Impossible to access Database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, health-check

I am currently getting crazy about my docker-compose really basic configuration which does not work as it should. I am trying to make it so one service depends on the MariaDB container properly loaded, to avoid tables initialization issue. Current state is that, whatever I add as environment variables for the MariaDB container configuration, my custom healthcheck fails and even accessing the container itself, I cannot login to the mariadb server.

The docker-compose looks as follows:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  dbs:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  mariadb:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_mariadb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASS: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: filecoin_dbs
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: mariadb --user=test --password=pass --silent --execute \"SELECT 1;\"
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - ./mounts/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
  dbs_filecoin:
    container_name: filecoin
    build: ./services/dbs_filecoin/
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      mariadb:
        condition: service_healthy
```

The `docker-compose up` command fails on the healthcheck, with message being:

```bash
balessan@balessan-laptop:~/workspace/servers/ocean-dbs$ docker-compose up
Starting dbs_mariadb ... 
ocean-dbs_dbs_1 is up-to-date
Starting dbs_mariadb ... done

ERROR: for dbs_filecoin  Container "84e98cb80c06" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

When I access the container using a basic: `docker exec -it dbs_mariadb bash` command, and check mysqladmin or try to login, I get the following:

```bash
root@84e98cb80c06:/# mariadb --user=test --password=pass --silent --execute \"SELECT 1;\"
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
bash: ": command not found
root@84e98cb80c06:/# mysqladmin status
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I also inspected the container status itself and it says basically the same:

```yaml
...
"Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 191,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-01-25T16:43:39.900674472+01:00",
                        "End": "2023-01-25T16:43:40.019637997+01:00",
                        "ExitCode": 127,
                        "Output": "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\n/bin/sh: 1: \": not found\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-01-25T16:43:41.029219694+01:00",
                        "End": "2023-01-25T16:43:41.144881651+01:00",
                        "ExitCode": 127,
                        "Output": "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\n/bin/sh: 1: \": not found\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-01-25T16:43:42.15481382+01:00",
                        "End": "2023-01-25T16:43:42.2625624+01:00",
                        "ExitCode": 127,
                        "Output": "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\n/bin/sh: 1: \": not found\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-01-25T16:43:43.273440938+01:00",
                        "End": "2023-01-25T16:43:43.407812286+01:00",
                        "ExitCode": 127,
                        "Output": "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\n/bin/sh: 1: \": not found\n"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2023-01-25T16:43:44.417770011+01:00",
                        "End": "2023-01-25T16:43:44.563060188+01:00",
                        "ExitCode": 127,
                        "Output": "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\n/bin/sh: 1: \": not found\n"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
...
```

I am starting to feel stupid so, any help really appreciated !

Comment: Looks like you need to login as the root user and [configure access rights for your user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/#granting-user-connections-from-remote-hosts)

Comment: Thanks @Garuno ! So my initial understanding that the container was responsible of assigning the proper rights based on the environment variables is wrong ?
I got it working using the root user/pass as a work-around, which is ok for development purpose.

Comment: Usually the DB is set up by the docker image. You can look at the code for this in `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` inside the docker container. Maybe you had already initialized the DB?